# Как узнать нажал ли пользователь и куда

Tags: javascript, html

У меня на сайте есть канвас и кнопка. Когда пользователь жмёт на кнопку, он должен нажать мышкой на место на канвасе. А после нажатия мне нужно узнать, нажал ли пользователь на канвас, если нет то начать все начало, а если и нажал на канвас, то узнать координаты его клика. Вопрос: как узнать нажал ли пользователь и на какие координаты?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/mouse-clicks

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить обработчик событя onclick на canvas, а координаты получить с помощью event.clientX и event.client Y

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]